# How to group requests in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, redux-observable

I need to load data for multiple charts. I also want to send the request only when chart settings change (`distinctUntilChanged`) and drop older requests (that do not reflect the current settings anymore - that's what the `switchMap` does). In `rxjs` and `redux-observable`, it would look like this:

```
export const chartsEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType('CHART_DATA_REQUESTED')
    // group actions by chart id...
    .groupBy(action => action.meta.chartId)
    // ...and for each chart:
    .map(actionsByChart$ =>
      actionsByChart$
        // continue only if settings change
        .distinctUntilChanged((a1, a2) => compare(a1.payload.settings, a2.payload.settings))
        // load data, but drop old requests when we get new settings
        .switchMap(action => 
          Observable.fromPromise(fetchChartData(action.payload.settings))
            .map(data => ({type: 'CHART_DATA.SUCCESS', payload: data, meta: action.meta))
            .catch(error => Observable.of({type: 'CHART_DATA.FAILURE', payload: error, meta: action.meta}))
        )
    )
    // combine actions for all charts into one output stream
    .mergeAll();
```

What is the comparable code in `redux-saga`?

Answer (score 1):

The generic way to achieve it:

```
function* syncChartsFlow(){
     var fetchTask = null;
     while(true){
          yield take([INITIAL_FETCH, SETTINGS_CHANGED])
          if(fetchTask){
              yield cancel(fetchTask)
          }
          fetchTask = yield fork(fetchChartsInfo)
     }
}

function* fetchChartsInfo(){
  // fetch info here
}
```

Comment: But this is just for one chart, correct? It does not handle grouping of requests _per chart_.